# Получить объект только с полями интерфейса в формате json

Tags: c#

Например есть класс:

```
 public class Group: IGroupe{

    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupeName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Students> Students { get; set; }
}
```

И есть интерфейс:

```
public interface IGroupe
{
    int GroupId { get; set; }
    string GroupeName { get; set; }
}
```

Как мне получить объект с полями только этого интерфейса в формате json?

```
IGroupe groupe=new Group();
```

Не работает, так нам доступны все поля при возвращении в формате json.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75091/discussion-on-question-by--------).

Answer (score 0):

Простой костыль выглядит так:

```
public static class JustGroupHelper
{
    public static JustGroup JustGroup(this IGroupe proto) => new JustGroup(proto);
}

public class JustGroup : IGroupe
{
    public JustGroup(IGroupe proto)
    {
        GroupId = proto.GroupId;
        GroupeName = proto.GroupeName;
    }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupeName { get; set; }
}
```

Теперь вы можете вызвать `Ok(groupe.JustGroup())`.

---

Как выяснилось в комментариях, `[JsonIgnore]` не вариант, т. к. должно быть можно отправить все поля тоже.

Comment: А если мне нужно достать список групп, которых очень-очень много, тогда же нужно пересоздать каждый обьект. Можно ли так делать?

Comment: @ДенисЧернов: Их больше 10 тысяч? Если нет, то проблем не вижу.

Comment: Это пример, мне вот еще нужно тоже самое с оценками сделать. Загрузить их все для обработки статистики на клиенте, проигнорировав некоторые поля. Их может быть намного больше нежели 10тис.

Comment: @ДенисЧернов: Тогда попробуйте как указано тут, и посмотрите, не слишком ли медленно. По идее, не должно быть.